# Webcam is not working in javascript. Yesterday it was working fine but now it is not working

Tags: javascript, webcam, getusermedia

In `script.js` I tried to access a webcam. Yesterday it was working fine but now it isn't and i have also allowed permission by site settings.

script.js

```
const videoGrid = document.getElementById('video-grid');
const myVideo = document.createElement('video');
myVideo.muted = true;

let myVideoStream;

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video:true,
    audio:true
}).then(stream => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo,stream);
})

const addVideoStream = (video,stream) => {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',() => {
        video.play();
    })
    videoGrid.append(video)
}
```

room.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Zoom Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is fine. Try it on a different browser. Check any additional code. Do some logging to try and pinpoint where it's going wrong on your machine.

Comment: Look at the console log in the browser devtools. Click on the lock icon in the browser location bar:you'll see the actual current Allow / Deny state of the webcam. Make sure the pages and javascript are served either from localhost or via https://. Try it with the most recent version of Google Chrome. Avoid Safari, IE, and legacy Edge browsers.